# How to check for ACCESS_KEY_SECRET AND ACCESS_KEY_ID sent by an application and these credentials are also stored in the Application table

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-models, django-views

An application is sending an api post request with  ACCESS_KEY_SECRET and ACCESS_KEY_ID in headers and other information in request body as i am not using any other authentication of DRF what i am doing is just simply matching the ACCESS_KEY_SECRET and ACCESS_KEY_ID of the api header to the ACCESS_KEY_SECRET and ACCESS_KEY_ID stored in Applicaion table, as i am new to python and django just want to check if i am doing it right.

## views.py

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def orderdetails(request):
    try:
        ACCESS_KEY_ID = request.META.get("HTTP_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
        ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = request.META.get("HTTP_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET")
        applications = Applications.objects.all()
        id = 0
        for e in applications:
            if e.ACCESS_KEY_ID == ACCESS_KEY_ID and e.ACCESS_KEY_SECRET == ACCESS_KEY_SECRET:
                id = e.id + id
                print(id)
                break
        else:
            return Response({"Message": "Enter Valid Credentials"})
    except ValueError:
        return Response({"ACCESS": "DENIED"})
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.data
        print(data)
        orders = Orders(
            applications=Applications.objects.get(id=id),
            purpose_code=data["purpose_code"],
            amount=data["amount"],
            currency=data["currency"],
            note=data["note"],
            payer_name=data["payer_name"],
            payer_email=data["payer_email"],
            payer_phone_country_code=data["payer_phone_country_code"],
            payer_phone_number=data["payer_phone_number"],
        )
        try:
            orders.full_clean()
        except ValidationError:
            return Response({"Error message": "invalid request body"})

        else:
            orders.save()
            serializer = OrderSerializer(orders)
            order_id = serializer.data["id"]
            access_token = serializer.data["access_token"]
            content = {"orderId": order_id, "accessToken": access_token}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        content = {"Error message": "invalid request body"}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## models.py

```
class Applications(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ACCESS_KEY_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    webhook_Auth_Token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

- Models should be named in singular: `Applications` -> `Application`; `Orders` -> `Order`.
- You don't need to define the `id` field if you don't want to override it.
- You should stick to one naming scheme – the most popular is `snake_case`. You're mixing and matching `camelCase` and `snake_Case_With_Caps` and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` now.
- You shouldn't look up *all* of your applications (consider the case where there might be 10,000 of them) to find one with the correct credentials. Instead, just use `.get()`:

  ```
  try:
      app = Applications.objects.get(
          isActive=True,
          ACCESS_KEY_ID=request.META["HTTP_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
          ACCESS_KEY_SECRET=request.META["HTTP_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET"],
      )
  except (KeyError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
      return Response({"Message": "Enter Valid Credentials"}, status=401)
  ```
- Since you seem to be using Django REST Framework, you should probably use a ViewSet instead of having to hand-manage the request methods, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AKY for your suggestions, i will surely make changes as you suggested.